# Troubleshooting Image Upload and Data Persistence in a React Form with Express Backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, fetch-api

[image: error-message]

I have this component called Whiteboard that houses a form. The form has an object consisting of a boolean, and five input fields, four of the five are text based inputs and the last one is an image input or rather a type file input that accepts images. When I submit the form I want to save it in a data.json file which is acting as a placeholder for the database that I will replace it with later like mongoDB. HOWEVER, when I hit submit I get a syntax error message in my console that I don’t understand. All I’m trying to do is fill out the form and use my handleSubmit function to save the object into my data.json file. And I'm doing this using a server.js file to handle my server-side logic at port 3500 while my front end is on localhost 3000, I’ve configured cors to handle this. The main issue is with the image that I'm trying to save in the object, I tried using base64 but that ended up giving me this ridiculously long piece that broke the structure of my json object, it looked like this:

```
[
 {
   "checkedService": true,
   "makeAndModel": "honda civic",
   "color": "white",
   "licensePlate": "MK12L7",
   "image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAQDAwQDAwQEBAQFBQQFBwsHBwYGBw4KCggLEA4RERAOEA8SFBoWEhMYEw8QFh8XGBsbHR0dERYgIh8cIhocHRz/2wBDAQUFBQcGBw0HBw0cEhASHBwcHBwcHBwcHBwcHBwcHBwcHBwcHBwcHBwcHBwcHBwcHBwcHBwcHBwcHBwcHBwcHBz/wgARCAEuAc0DAREAAhEBAxEB/8QAHQAAAQQDAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMEBQYCBwgBCf/…(This went on for 18 more pages of just random whatever this was.)
   "carMessage": "hi mom",
   "type": "car"
 }
]
```

Using this as my previous handleSubmit:

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const newCartEntry = {...carFormData, type: 'car'}; // formatData.image should already be a a Base64 string
        
        fetch('http://localhost:3500/car', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(newCartEntry)
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.headers.get('Content-Type').includes('application/json')) {
                return response.json();
            }
            throw new Error('Server did not return JSON.');
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log('Success:', data);
            // Update cart state with response from server if needed
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
        // Use functional update form to ensure you get the most up-to-date state
        setCart((currentCart) => {
          const updatedCart = [...currentCart];
          if (editingIndex != null) {
            updatedCart[editingIndex] = newCartEntry;
          } else {
            updatedCart.push(newCartEntry);
          }
          return updatedCart;
        });
        
        resetCarForm();
    };
```

This is my current Whiteboard component:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { ImageIcon } from "lucide-react";

function WhiteBoard() {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
  const [editingIndex, setEditingIndex] = useState(null);
  const [carPreview, setCarPreview] = useState(null);
  const [carFormData, setCarFormData] = useState({
    checkedService: false,
    makeAndModel: '',
    color: '',
    licensePlate: '',
    image: null,
    carMessage: ''
  });

  const fileInputRef = useRef();

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value, type, checked } = event.target;
    if (type === 'checkbox') {
      setCarFormData({ ...carFormData, [name]: checked });
    } else {
      setCarFormData({ ...carFormData, [name]: value });
    }
  };

  const resetCarForm = () => {
    setCarFormData({
      checkedService: false,
      makeAndModel: '',
      color: '',
      licensePlate: '',
      image: null,
      carMessage: ''
    });
    setCarPreview(null);
    if (fileInputRef.current) {
      fileInputRef.current.value = "";
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('checkedService', carFormData.checkedService);
    formData.append('makeAndModel', carFormData.makeAndModel);
    formData.append('color', carFormData.color);
    formData.append('licensePlate', carFormData.licensePlate);
    formData.append('carMessage', carFormData.carMessage);
    formData.append('type', 'car');
    if (carFormData.image) {
      formData.append('image', carFormData.image); // This is the File object
    }

    fetch('http://localhost:3500/car', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    })
    .then(response =>  response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log('Success:', data);
        // Update cart state with response from server if needed
        setCart((currentCart) => {
          const updatedCart = [...currentCart];
          if (editingIndex != null) {
            updatedCart[editingIndex] = { ...carFormData, id: data.id }; // Assuming 'data.id' is returned by the server
          } else {
            updatedCart.push({ ...carFormData, id: data.id });
          }
          return updatedCart;
        });
        resetCarForm();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
};

  const handleImageChange = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        setCarPreview(reader.result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      setCarFormData({ ...carFormData, image: file }); // Store the File object
    }
  };

  const handleIconClick = () => {
    fileInputRef.current.click();
  };


  console.log(cart)
  return (
    <>
      <form id="car-service-form" className='service-box__detail' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input 
          type='checkbox'
          name='checkedService'
          className='carServiceBox' 
          id='car'
          checked={carFormData.checkedService}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          required/>
        <label htmlFor='car' className='car-service-label'>
          <div className='service-button'>
            <span className='circle'></span>
            <span className='subject'>Clear snow of vehicle</span>
          </div>
          <span className='price'>$20</span>
        </label>
        <div className='car-service-top'>
          <div className='car-specs'>
            <input 
            className='car-spec' 
            placeholder='Make & Model' 
            name='makeAndModel'
            value={carFormData.makeAndModel}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            required/>
            <input 
            className='car-spec' 
            placeholder='Color'
            name='color'
            value={carFormData.color}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            required/>
            <input 
            className='car-spec' 
            placeholder='License Plate'
            name='licensePlate'
            value={carFormData.licensePlate}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className='upload-area'>
            {carPreview ? (
              <img 
              src={carPreview} 
              alt="Preview" 
              className="uploaded-image-preview"
              style={{ maxWidth: '100px', cursor: 'pointer' }}
              onClick={handleIconClick}/>) : (
              <div htmlFor='image-upload' className='upload-label' onClick={handleIconClick}>
              <ImageIcon size={90} className='imageIcon'/>
              <p className='words'>Optional: Upload Image</p>
            </div> )}
            {<input 
              id='image-upload'
              type='file' 
              name='image'
              className='image-upload' 
              accept="image/*" 
              ref={fileInputRef}
              onChange={handleImageChange}
              style={{ display: 'none' }}/>} 
          </div>
        </div>
        <textarea 
          rows='5' 
          cols='20' 
          className='carMessage' 
          placeholder='Opional Message: My tip depends on your the performance.'
          name='carMessage'
          value={carFormData.carMessage}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        <div className='car service-detail-bottom'>
          <div className='bottom-buttons'>
            <button type='submit' className='push'>Push</button>
          </div>
          <p onClick={() => resetCarForm()} className='words'>RESET</p>
        </div>
      </form> 
    </>
  );
}

export default WhiteBoard;
```

my server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const port = 3500;

// Enable CORS for all routes
app.use(cors());

// Middleware to parse JSON body
app.use(bodyParser.json());


// The file where my data is currently stored
const DATA_FILE = path.join(__dirname, './data.json');

// POST route for /car
app.post('/car', (req, res) => {
    // Read existing data from db.json
    fs.readFile(DATA_FILE, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Error reading file:", err);
            return res.status(500).send('An error occurred reading the DB.');
        }

        // Parse the current data to an array
        let DB = JSON.parse(data);

        // Add the new car entry to the current data
        DB.push(req.body);

        // Write the updated database object back to db.json
        fs.writeFile(DATA_FILE, JSON.stringify(DB, null, 2), 'utf8', (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Error writing file:", err);
                return res.status(500).send('An error occurred writing to the database');
            }

            console.log(DB)
            res.status(201).send({message:'New car service object added to the DB.'});
        });
    });
});

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

my data.json file:

```
[]
```

Comment: what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Its the first thing in my post. The picture before the paragraph. Error: SyntaxError: unexpected token 'N', "New car se" ... is not valid JSON